# How can I copy all of the URLs that appear in the Network tab in Firefox in the Developer Toolbar?

Tags: file, firefox, http-status-code-404

I have bought a template that comes with hundreds if not thousands of files (Javascript, images, plugins, etc.). I have now chosen one of the homepages (out of many) that I want to use. Rather than copying thousands of files, I'd like to JUST copy those that I am really using. So I have copied the HTML file to a new folder, and opened it in Firefox. In the Network tab of the Developer Toolbar I can easily see which files are missing (404 response). There are 60 files.

Now, in order to make my life easy I'd like to write a simply command line script that copies those files from the original template folder to my new folder. To do that, I need the URLs for each site. But it means I'd have to right click on each file and go to COPY URL. That is getting very boring. How can I somehow select them all and get all the URLs?

[image: developer toolbar]

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have figured this one out is to click on the settings cog in the top right of the view, and click "Copy all as HAR", then paste that result into VSCode or another text editor and use a regular expression to extract the URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [jonesy827's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76843150/399105), I extracted all the URLs using [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/):

1. First, click the settings button near the top right of the network tab > *Save all as HAR*
2. Next, use jq to extract the URLs:

   ```
   jq -r '.log.entries[].request.url' requests.har
   ```